# SCDF kubernetes custom source is writing data to "ouput" channel

Tags: spring, kubernetes, cloud

I have custom source application which reads data from external kafka server and pass the information to next processor in the stream. In local everything works perfect. I have created docker image of the code and when i deploy stream in kubernetes env, i do see topic with the name stream.source-app got created but messages produced by source are actually going to "output" topic. I dont see this issue in local env.

application.yaml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        Workitemconnector_subscribe:
          destination: Workitemconnector
          contentType: application/json
          group: SCDFMessagingSourceTestTool1
          consumer:
            partitioned: true
            concurrency: 1
            headerMode: embeddedHeaders        
        output:
#          destination: dataOut
          binder: kafka2              
      binders:
        kafka1:
         type: kafka
         environment:
           spring:
             cloud:
               stream:
                kafka:
                  binder:
                    brokers: xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9092
                    zkNodes: xx.xxx.xx.xxx:2181
        kafka2:
         type: kafka
         environment:
           spring:
             cloud:
               stream:
                 kafka:
                   binder:
                     brokers: server1:9092
                     zkNodes: server1:2181
spring.cloud.stream.defaultBinder: kafka1
```

In local without defining any parameters during stream deployment, i notice source is consuming message from xxxx server and producing data to server1 and to the topic name "stream.sourceapp" but in kubernetes env it is acting strange. It is always sending data to "output" topic even though "stream.sourceapp" topic exists

Comment: So the env variable is setup incorrectly? I'm not sure if I understand what is the issue here.

Comment: I am expecting source will write the data to topic "stream.sourceapp" because that is the topic processor is listening to. But source is writing to "output" topic. So processor is forever waiting for the message.

Comment: which environment variable do we need to set? in local i am not setting any environment variable.

Comment: Can you post your `deployment` yaml?

Comment: I was not able to add application yaml content here so added it in the main post itself